# Multiple Unresolved class in AndroidManifest.xml. Error when using sharing_intent plugin MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-intent, android-manifest, flutter-plugin

I know that I'm asking two questions at once, but I don't know if it could be related.

I can't get to solve all the unresolved classes from the `AndroidManifest.xml`
[image: As you can see I get the red flags on multiple lines.]
I've tried multiple things:

1. `Invalidating Caches/Restart`
2. `flutter clean`
3. Adding `rest.clinimetric.MainActivity` to try and solve at least one problem
4. Create a simple app to check if would get the same error. It did.

This is the whole error that I'm getting when using the plugin receive_sharing_intent. It pops when I open a pdf with my app. I don't understand though that the error pops on the Pixel 3A while not on a Samsung A40. There is something more specific on this that I'm missing?

```
W/FlutterActivity(12757): Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@fa044bb) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.
D/HostConnection(12757): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf2754470, tid 12844
D/HostConnection(12757): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/EGL_emulation(12757): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf2542690: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xbc509e10) (first time)
I/Choreographer(12757): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel
receive_sharing_intent/events-media:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel
receive_sharing_intent/events-media)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
#2      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:542:29)
#3      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:528:64)
#8      CastStream.listen (dart:_internal/async_cast.dart:17:17)
#11     _ClinimetricHomePageState.initState (package:clinimetric/main.dart:147:47)
#12     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4684:58)
#13     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
...     Normal element mounting (132 frames)
#145    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
#146    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5991:32)
...     Normal element mounting (258 frames)
#404    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
#405    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
#406    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
#407    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:397:11)
#408    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
#409    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
#410    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#417    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:223:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#424    _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:188:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#431    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:223:11)
#432    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
#433    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
#434    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1174:16)
#435    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1145:5)
#436    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1087:17)
#437    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2620:19)
#438    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1086:13)
#439    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:927:7)
#440    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:908:7)
(elided 17 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by services library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel receive_sharing_intent/events-media:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel receive_sharing_intent/events-media)

etc... because it's calling 4 functions, so for each of them the error pops up
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate the same errors you got on your Manifest file. Have you tried running the complete [sample app](https://github.com/KasemJaffer/receive_sharing_intent) and see if it works? Make sure that Android Studio and the Flutter plugin that you're using is up-to-date.

You can also try running `flutter doctor` to check for any errors or warnings.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply! Yes everything is up-to-date and I've already tried it with sample app and flutter doctor, but still i get the errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated